# Finite-dimensional subspaces of normed linear spaces are closed: Do there exist alternative proofs?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

It is well-known that each finite-dimensional subspace $F$ of a (real or complex) normed linear space $(V,\lVert - \rVert)$ is closed. The standard proof is this.

$\lVert - \rVert$ induces a norm $\lVert - \rVert_F$ on $F$. Since all norms on $F$ are equivalent, $(F,\lVert - \rVert_F)$ is complete so that $F$ is closed in $(V,\lVert - \rVert)$.

Let us now consider a *finite-dimensional* $V$ and a codimension $1$ subspace $F$. I tried to find a "direct proof" that $F$ is closed in $V$, but all my attempts were in vain. By a direct proof I mean one based on elementary properties of norms (essentially the triangle inequality).

Question: Does there exist a proof not using the "heavy gun" that all norms on finite-dimensional linear spaces are equivalent?

Comment: You may use the continuity of linear forms.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Okay, that would require the Hahn-Banach theorem. Or are there more elementary proofs for the continuity of linear functionals?

Comment: Aren’t linear maps in normed and finite dimensional vector spaces continuous per se?

Comment: If I may ask, what's the motivation ? (I've never heard the "all norms are equivalent" argument being referred to as a "heavy guns" argument)

Comment: @MichaelHoppe They are surely continuous, but it requires a proof which is not trivial. The only proof I know  uses Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Well, all these facts (the ones in the question and the comments) rely on one basic fact: if $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ are linearly independent then $\sum a_i v_i \to a_k$ is continuous for each $k$. We can prove this using by going to Euclidean space and using Bolzano -Wierstrass Theorem  but the proof is a bit messy. We don't have to use any theorem other than Bolzano -Wierstrass for this.

Comment: @Max Perhaps it is exaggerated to call it a "heavy gun", but the norm equivalence theorem is usually based on a compactness argument. I was interested whether this can be avoided.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Doesn't it again use the norm equivalence theorem?

Comment: No, you can take a sequence of linear combinations of $v_i$'s, look at the coefficients as a sequence of vectors in Euclidean space and use Bolzano-Wierstrass to prove continuity. Only definition of norm is required for this proof.

Comment: I see. But it's actually a local compactness argument; and since none of this works for $\mathbb{Q}$, perhaps it's a sign that local compactness is what's essential here ?